# Calculate percentage with BigDecimals

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to calculate the of a number I receive in BigDecimal format :

```
BigDecimal number1 = new BigDecimal("17");
int percentage = 50;
BigDecimal percentageAmount = number1.multiply(new BigDecimal(percentage/100));
```

but I got a 0 !

Comment: Solution 1: `number1.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(percentage/100.0))` --- Solution 2: `number1.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(percentage)).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))`

Comment: To elucidate: the problem is that 50 is an integer, and 100 is an integer.  So when it gets to 50/100 it doesn't magically change the result into a fraction (floating point number), it does integer maths on it, and integer maths doesn't have any fractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the divided result to `double`. The integer division is returning zero as expected. This should work.

```
BigDecimal percentageAmount = number1.multiply(new BigDecimal((double)percentage/100));
```

Or, make the 100 to 100.0.

```
BigDecimal percentageAmount = number1.multiply(new BigDecimal(percentage/100.0));
```

These solutions would work if the number is small as you have used. But these solutions won't give the precise results when the number is big. This would be the **best approach** for avoiding the precision error:

```
BigDecimal percentageAmount = number1.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf((double)percentage/100));
```